# Bash: Why does egrepping for this string succeed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I'm trying to check if a help switch was passed to my program via egrepping it for `-?`, `-h`, or `--help`. If not, I simply forward everything to another script, like so:

```
if echo "$*" | egrep -q -- '-?|-h|--help'; then
    help
    exit 0
fi

exec another/script "$@"
```

For some reason, this doesn't seem to be working on my system. I tracked it down to the fact `egrep` was returning successfully for searches on the empty string, e.g. this will print `0`:

```
echo '' | egrep -q -- '-?|-h|--help'
echo $?
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it? Thanks!

---

**edit:** Also just noticed that while this command will succeed:

```
echo -h | egrep -- -?
echo $? # 0
```

Using it with regular `grep` will fail:

```
echo -h | grep -- -?
echo $? # 1
```

I'm assuming the extended grep is treating `?` as a special character, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions, `?` means zero or one copy of the preceding character, which in this case is `-`. So the `-?` means zero or one matches of `-`. Zero matches of `-` matches the empty string, so this regular expression will match everything. You need to escape the `?` so it will be interpreted literally, not as a regular expression metacharacter.

```
egrep -q -- '-\?|-h|--help'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `?` is a special pattern character in the shell and it is treated differently in a *regular expression*. Take a look at man bash:

```
Pattern Matching
...
The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
...
?      Matches any single character
```

So in your example:

```
echo -h | egrep -- -?
echo $? # 0
```

`'?'` is zero or 1 repetitions of the preceding character `-`. (as correctly pointed out in the comments) In a *Regular Expression* `'?'` loses its special meaning to match a single character and instead means a match of `zero` or `1` times. To preserve the character itself you would need an explicit requests for `-` and `?` themselves such as in a *character class*

```
echo -h | egrep -- [-][?]
echo $?
1
```

Comment: Isn't the problem rather that `?` *does* mean something in regex but that it doesn't mean "single character" but rather "zero or one" so `-?` means either `-` or the empty string and the empty string *always* matches?

Comment: The reference to `man bash` you give describes globs, not regular expressions.

Comment: The reference to *man bash* was the reference to *Pattern Matching* -- thank you Etan, yes I was not clear.